# How to represent one to one mapped class as columns in another class

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

Suppose there is an Employee and Experience class

```
@Entity
class Employee {
    @Id
    private int empId;
    private Experience experience;
}
```

```
class Experience {
    private Integer experienceInMonth;
    private Integer experienceInYears; 
}
```

Even though Experience is not Entity , I want to add its properties (experienceInMonth, experienceInYears) as column in Employee table . I do not wish wish to create Experience as a seperate Table but want to use its viarable as column.

Employee tabe conatin following fields - empId, experienceInMonth, experienceInYears

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable`:

```java
@Entity
class Employee {
    @Id
    private int empId;
    @Embedded // Add this
    private Experience experience;
}

@Embeddable // Add this
class Experience {
    private Integer experienceInMonth;
    private Integer experienceInYears; 
}
```